# What happens when passing reference to literal in C++?

Tags: c++

What happens here:

```
double foo( const double& x ) {
   // do stuff with x
}

foo( 5.0 );
```

1. Does the compiler create an anonymous variable and sets its value to 5.0?
2. Does the x reference a memory location in read-only memory? This is a weird phrasing, I know...

**edit**: I forgot the const keyword...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A temporary variable is created for this purpose and it's usually created on stack.

You could try to const_cast, but it's pontless anyway, since you can no longer access a variable once the function returns.

Comment: This seems very inefficient to me. Wouldn't it be better to just create a memory location in Read Only segment with the declared value and use it instead of creating a variable on the stack? All behind the scenes, of course...

Comment: That's implementation dependent anyway. And double is not that large.

Comment: Temporary variable creation holds good for Objects as well. Instead of double if it were a Class then a temporary object would have got created and its constructor also would have got called.

Comment: The question is specific to primitives. Creating a variable on the stack seems like a bit of waste, not just the memory (in case of recursion, maybe?!?!), but run-time wise as well.
I guess implementation dependent is all there is...

Comment: Not necessarily such a waste. If you pass a value allocated in static storage the code that accesses it will have to read it and this can reduce cache locality.

Answer (score 1):

1. What compiler probably does create const literal, but that's not a variable.
2. A non-const reference cannot point to a literal.

   $ g++ test.cpp
   test.cpp: In function `int main()':
   test.cpp:10: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'double&' from a temporary of type 'double'
   test.cpp:5: error: in passing argument 1 of`double foo(double&)'

test.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double foo(double & x) {
    x = 1;
}

int main () {
    foo(5.0);

    cout << "hello, world" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

On the other hand, you could pass a literal to a const reference as follows.
test2.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double foo(const double & x) {
    cout << x << endl;
}

int main () {
    foo(5.0);

    cout << "hello, world" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```