# "A reference may be bound only to an object", why is "const int &ref = 3;" valid?

Tags: c++, reference, initialization, constants

I am just starting learning c++. I found an advice on Internet: "Learn with a good book, it is better than videos on youtube." So as I am motivated and I have time I learn with c++ Primer 5th Ed.

In this book, they say:
Note: "A reference is not an object. Instead, a reference is just another name for an already existing object."

and:
"a reference may be bound only to an object, not to a literal or to the result of a more general expression"

I understand:

```
int i = 3;
int &ri = i;  // is valid: ri is a new name for i
int &ri2 = 2;  // is not valid: 2 is not an object
```

Then I don't understand why:

```
const int &ri3 = 2;  // is valid
```

They write: "It can be easier to understand complicated pointer or reference declarations if
you read them from right to left."

Ok, it is not very complicated. I understand: 
I declare a variable named ri3,
it is a reference (a reference when & is after the type, an address when & is in an expression)
to an object of type int
and it is a constant.

I think it has already been explained many times but when I search on forums I find complicated (to me) answers to complicated problems, and I still don't understand.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `2` is a literal which you can't change. `const` ensures that reference points to a const entity, thus you can't change the object that you refer to by reference.

Comment: `"a reference may be bound only to an object, not to a literal or to the result of a more general expression"` is only true in some cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7701261/1508519

> You cannot bind a literal to a reference to non-const (because
>   modifying the value of a literal is not an operation that makes
>   sense). You can however bind a literal to a reference to const.

http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/

> The "const" is important. The first line is an error and the code
>   won’t compile portably with this reference to non-const, because f()
>   returns a temporary object (i.e., rvalue) and only lvalues can be
>   bound to references to non-const.

For illustrative purposes see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/661281/1508519).

> A non-const reference cannot point to a literal.

The following code will produce an error.

> error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type
>   'double&' from an rvalue of type 'double'

```
#include <iostream>

double foo(double & x) {
    x = 1;
}

int main () {
    foo(5.0);
    return 0;
}
```

Here's [Lightness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20443262/a-reference-may-be-bound-only-to-an-object-why-is-const-int-ref-3-valid/20443362#comment30541163_20443362)' comment.

> [C++11: 5.1.1/1]: [..] A string literal is an lvalue; all other
>   literals are prvalues.

And [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) (scroll down to `rvalue (until C++11) / prvalue (since C++11)`):

> A prvalue ("pure" rvalue) is an expression that identifies a temporary
>   object (or a subobject thereof) or is a value not associated with any
>   object.
>
> The following expressions are prvalues:
>
> ```
> Literal (except string literal), such as 42 or true or nullptr.
> ```

Comment: `[C++11: 5.1.1/1]: [..] A string literal is an lvalue; all other
literals are prvalues.`

Answer (score 1):

It is valid because number literals are actually constants. So the compiler can accept such reference only if it is `const`.

Comment: `const` and "constant" are two different things. Consider `const int r = rand();`

Comment: @KeithThompson: Yes, so what? Literals are constants thats why cont references can accept that. I haven't said it's valid in reverse.

Comment: Your conclusion happens to be correct, but it doesn't follow from your premise. It's fairly obvious why `int &ri3 = 2;` (without the `const`) is invalid, but that doesn't imply that `const int &ri3 = 2;` is valid. As I understand it, the compiler has to create an implicit read-only object so that `ri3` can be a reference to it; note that `&ri3` yields a valid address. There must be a special language rule for that. For that matter, there could as easily be a special rule to make `int &ri3 = 2;` valid; it just happens that there isn't.